# Chain UIView animations with time intervals

Tags: iphone, ios, uikit, core-animation, objective-c-blocks

I need to animate 3 UIViews (fade in/out).
1 animation duration is 0.6s (fade in/out cycle is 0.6+0.6s). But I need to launch animations in 0.2 seconds.

- 1st animation should be launched in 0.0 seconds.
- 2nd animation should be launched in 0.2 seconds.
- 3rd animation should be launched in 0.4 seconds.

And all of them should be looped "indefinitely" (until some trigger).

What I have at the moment:

```
- (void)playAnimation {
    isAnimated = YES;
    [self animateView:firstView afterDelay:0.0];
    [self animateView:secondView afterDelay:0.2];
    [self animateView:thirdView afterDelay:0.4];
}

- (void)stopAnimation {
    isAnimated = NO;
}

- (void)animateView:(UIView *)animatedView afterDelay:(float)delay {
    if(isAnimated) {
        [UIView animateWithDuration:0.6 delay:delay options:UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionNone
                     animations:^ {
            animatedView.alpha = 1.0;
        } completion:^(BOOL finished) {
            [UIView animateWithDuration:0.6 animations:^ {
                animatedView.alpha = 0.0;
            } completion:^(BOOL finished) {
                [self animateView:animatedView afterDelay:0.0];
            }];
        }];
    }
}
```

This code works unpredictable. Sometimes view animation works like I want (with phase 0.2 seconds), some times it starts in the same time...
What will be the proper way to do that? I've also tried to remove `afterDelay:` part from method signature and launch animateView method like that with exactly same effect:

```
[self performSelector:@selector(animateView:) withObject:thirdView afterDelay:0.6];
```

**UPDATE**
I've noticed that animation "breaks" when heavy networking stuff is performing in background (loading big images using AFNetworking).
I don't mind if animation will "freeze" a bit (though I prefer to not have delays at all) but I really want to keep phases of all animations linked (with same phase difference).

To make problem easier to understand I've added graphs. Y is alpha, X is time. Top 3 graphs - what I want to have. Bottom ones - what I currently have. Highlighted area is where problem comes. You can see that second view's animation freeze for 0.2 seconds and synchronise with 3rd one. So they start blinking in the same phase. This is just one example. Some times they can animate ok, sometimes all 3 views "syncronize" in few rounds of animation and blink in same phase...
[image: Animation]

Comment: Not sure about the problem, but a better way to do infinite animation is to use `UIViewAnimationOptionRepeat | UIViewAnimationOptionAutoreverse` options. To end, just add a small animation to the desired end value with `UIViewAnimationOptionBeginFromCurrentState`.

Comment: Thanks, I knew this option. I just want to finish animations "nicely".   If I'll set `isAnimated = NO` - each cycle of animation will stop after completion. So all views will be faded out after that. In your case I think I'll need to stop animations immediately.

Comment: Not immediately, if you start another (non-repeating) animation to fade it out, it will go away nice and slow. But, yes, it won't be "aligned" to the previous animation cycles.

Comment: It may easier to use a timer and not use the on completion block.

Comment: @Mar0ux thanks. But how will I know what will be duration of the "small animation" at the end? I mean when I stop animation all views are in different "phases". So I need to know should I fade in and then fade out, or just fade out. Also I need to know time left for each view (<1.2). I can't see any reasonably easy way to do that...

Comment: So why don't you just begin the animations all at once but pass 0.0, 0.2, and 0.4 to the _delay_ argument of `+[UIView animateWithDuration:delay:options:animations:completion:]`? You can also pass the same animation block 3 times. Or, you could try the solution I proposed. Not sure how you can infinite animations view the `UIView` API.

Comment: @OgreSwamp RE your latest edit - are you sure the networking stuff is not happening on main thread? One (slightly hackish) way to determine time remaining for last animation is to calculate phase based on the intermittent alpha value while the views are animating.

Comment: @neilsbot I do exactly same - passing 0.0, 0.2 and 0.4 to delay. As you can see in my first example. But because views animated independently any delay in queue cause unsyncronization of animations.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Looks like you want the same animation, applied to all 3 views, offset by t=0.2. You can use Core Animation to do exactly what you want with very little effort.

Doing it this way they will always be timed correctly.

I propose this:

```
-(void)playAnimation
{
    CABasicAnimation * anim = [ CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"opacity" ] ;
    anim.autoreverses = YES ;
    anim.repeatCount = CGFLOAT_MAX ;
    anim.removedOnCompletion = NO ;
    anim.duration = 0.6 ;
    anim.fromValue = @0.0 ;
    anim.toValue = @1.0;

    // finish configuring your animation here (timing function, speed, duration, fill mode, etc) ...

    CFTimeInterval t = CACurrentMediaTime() ;

    anim.beginTime = t ;
    [ self.firstView.layer addAnimation:anim forKey:@"opacity-anim" ] ; // name is so you can remove this anim later

    anim.beginTime += 0.2 ;
    [ self.secondView.layer addAnimation:anim forKey:@"opacity-anim" ] ;

    anim.beginTime += 0.2 ;
    [ self.thirdView.layer addAnimation:anim forKey:@"opacity-anim" ] ; // name is so you can remove this anim later
}

-(void)stopAnimation
{
    [ self.firstView.layer removeAnimationForKey:@"opacity-anim" ] ;
    [ self.secondView.layer removeAnimationForKey:@"opacity-anim" ] ;
    [ self.thirdView.layer removeAnimationForKey:@"opacity-anim" ] ;
}
```

**edit**: oops! forgot the start, end values!

Comment: was going to write something similar, beat me to it:)

Comment: To handle the smooth fade after removing the repeating animations, ads new animations with toValue=0. That should do it. Each animation can also have a delegate which will tell you when the animations complete.

Comment: Thanks. This solution works for me. Ye I need smooth fade out, so I'll implement that too.

Comment: Will award bounty in 4 hours (SO doesn't allow me to do it now)

Comment: @nielsbot Was trying to implement smooth transition. The stop call can be triggered in any time, so we don't know what the current state of the alpha for each dot. Let's say "stop" was triggered at 1.8s in the graph. I want last view to fade in to 1.0 and them fade out. So animation duration for last view will be 1s. I don't really know animation for last fade out. Any idea how that can be implemented?

Comment: It will be tricky to have it animate to a complete cycle. You can fade to 0 from the current opacity: Add a new CABasicAnimation for alpha, with fromValue = [ layer presentationLayer ].opacity and toValue = 0. Set the fillMode to "both", add that animation, then remove the current animation.

Comment: The only other thing I can think of is to schedule the removal of the animations using an NSTimer. Have the timer wake up at the time you want your animation removed (after completing the next full cycle for each layer)... You may get a visual artifact however if the timer is delayed, etc.

Comment: Is there any way to trigger delegate on end of animation cycle?

Comment: Did you try it? Not sure if it gets called every time or not. You could also try removing the animation you want to end and adding it back with repeatCount set to 1 more than the current number of cycles. There's a way to do it. I know however that to synchronize your animations properly you should rely on this method. Good luck.

Comment: Actually--I think you should ask another Q on SO, no?

Answer (score 1):

The way to schedule animations properly is by using the `CAMediaTiming` protocol that the `CAKeyframeAnimation` class conforms to. See my answer below for links to resources on how to achieve this.

[Changing speed of an ongoing CAKeyframeAnimation animation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8378120/changing-speed-of-an-ongoing-cakeyframeanimation-animation/8419729#8419729)

Answer (score 0):

Try instead of performSelector: the following sample

```
- (void)animateView:(UIView *)animatedView afterDelay:(float)delay {
    dispatch_after(dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, delay * NSEC_PER_SEC), dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        if(isAnimated) {
            [UIView animateWithDuration:0.6 delay:0.0 options:UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionNone
                         animations:^ {
                animatedView.alpha = 1.0;
            } completion:^(BOOL finished) {
                [UIView animateWithDuration:0.6 animations:^ {
                    animatedView.alpha = 0.0;
                } completion:^(BOOL finished) {
                    [self animateView:animatedView afterDelay:0.0];
                }];
            }];
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Hope it will work as what you want.

```
- (void)animateView:(UIView *)animatedView afterDelay:(float)delay
{
    if(isAnimated) {
        [UIView animateWithDuration:0.6 delay:delay options:UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionNone
                         animations:^ {
                             animatedView.alpha = 1.0;
                         } completion:^(BOOL finished) {
                             [UIView animateWithDuration:0.6 delay:delay options:UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionNone animations:^{
                                  animatedView.alpha = 0.0;
                             } completion:^(BOOL finished) {
                                 [self animateView:animatedView afterDelay:delay];
                             }];
                         }];
    }
}
```

This is just some modification of your code.

Answer (score -2):

Try this, this might work for you.

```
- (void)playAnimation {
    isAnimated = YES;

    [self performSelector:@selector(animateView:) withObject:firstView afterDelay:0.1];
    [self performSelector:@selector(animateView:) withObject:secondView afterDelay:0.2];
    [self performSelector:@selector(animateView:) withObject:thirdView afterDelay:0.4];
}


- (void)animateView:(UIView *)animatedView {
   //Here "animatedView" will contain (firstView/secondView/thirdView) whatever you are passing
   //your animation
}
```

Comment: ohh..sorry I didn't notice that.