# Is it possible in Obj-c to have an animation block animate another block?

Tags: ios, objective-c, block

Is appears this is possible.  But wonder if there is a better way? What I am trying to do is make a custom component that allows the user to send over the properties they want to animate my custom object onto the screen. I also want to allow them the ability to send over a hide animation block where I animate the properties they send over in the hide block.  For example, they might send over the show block with alpha = 1.0 & frame size. Then in the hide block they might say frame and color to white.

```
void (^testBlock)(void) = ^{
    self.alpha = 0.0f;
};

[UIView animateWithDuration:2.0 animations:^{
    // some block
    testBlock();

} completion:^(BOOL finished) {
    //
}];
```

Comment: here is one way to coordinate animations: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16771714/chain-uiview-animations-with-time-intervals/16966982#16966982

Answer (score 1):

I think what you're asking is whether or not you can pass an animation block to the UIView animation method. Something like this - and notice you just pass the block name as the parameter.

```
void (^testBlock)(void) = ^{
    self.alpha = 0.0f;
};

[UIView animateWithDuration:2.0 animations: testBlock
completion:^(BOOL finished) {
    // do something
}];
```